Help with addLiquidtyEth keeps returning either transfer_from Failed or OVERFLOw
Im trying to add all tokens to liquidity. It doesnt allow the amount of tokens desired to be more then the total supply so im not sure why it keeps returning 'execution reverted: pancake: OVERFLOW'
Im trying the same code (with proper routers etc) on base and eth aswell and continue to get the same errors. If its not a TRANFER_FROM error then it's an OVERFLOW error. It lets me add liquidity if im doing small amounts say my total supply is 100,000,000,000,000,000. The only way i can add liquidity is if i give it a much smaller number like 10000.
async def add_liquidity_bsc(token_address, amount_token_desire, amount_token_minimum, amount_eth_min, burn=False,
                            receiver=None):
    try:
        pancakeRouter_addy = web3.to_checksum_address(router_address)
        token_address = web3.to_checksum_address(token_address)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error while converting address to checksum: {e}')
        pancakeRouter_addy = router_address

    amount_token_min = float(amount_token_minimum) - 10

    router = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeRouter_addy, abi=pancakeswapRouter)

    deadline_minutes = 20
    current_timestamp = web3.eth.get_block('latest')['timestamp']
    deadline = current_timestamp + (deadline_minutes * 60)

    if burn:
        receiver_of_lp = account.address
    else:
        receiver_of_lp = receiver if receiver else account.address

    amount_token_desired = Web3.to_wei(amount_token_desire, 'ether')
    amount_token_min = Web3.to_wei(amount_token_min, 'ether')
    amount_bnb = Web3.to_wei(amount_eth_min, 'ether')

    try:
        token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=token_address, abi=await getContractAbi(token_address))

        token_balance = token_contract.functions.balanceOf(account.address).call()
        print(token_balance)
        print(amount_token_desired)

        if int(amount_token_desired) > token_balance:
            amount_token_desired = token_balance
            print(f"Insufficient balance to add liquidity, {token_balance}")
        try:

            approve_tx = token_contract.functions.approve(pancakeRouter_addy, amount_token_desired).build_transaction({
                'from': account.address,
                'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address),
                'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(2, 'gwei'),
            })
            signed_approve_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve_tx, private_key=private_key)
            approve_tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_approve_tx.rawTransaction)
            web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(approve_tx_hash)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"failed to approve {e}")

        custom_gas_price = web3.to_wei(5, 'gwei')
        try:
            estimated_gas = router.functions.addLiquidityETH(
                token_address,  # Token address
                amount_token_desired,  # Desired amount of token
                0,  # Minimum amount of token
                0,  # Minimum amount of ETH
                receiver_of_lp,  # Receiver of LP tokens
                deadline,
            ).estimate_gas({
                'from': account.address,
                'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address) + 1,
                'value': amount_bnb
            })

            print(f'estimated: {estimated_gas}\nCustom: {custom_gas_price}')
            cost = estimated_gas * custom_gas_price
            print('cost: ', cost)
        except Exception as e:
            print('failed to estimate gas: ', e)
            estimated_gas = 401911

        add_liquidity_tx = router.functions.addLiquidityETH(
            token_address,  # Token address
            amount_token_desired,  # Desired amount of token
            amount_token_min,  # Minimum amount of token
            amount_bnb,  # Minimum amount of ETH
            receiver_of_lp,  # Receiver of LP tokens
            deadline,
        ).build_transaction({
            'from': account.address,
            'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address) + 1,
            'gasPrice': custom_gas_price,
            'gas': estimated_gas,
            'value': amount_bnb

        })
        print('sent add lp trany')

        signed_add_liquidity_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(add_liquidity_tx, private_key=private_key)
        print('signed')
        add_liquidity_tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_add_liquidity_tx.rawTransaction)

        web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(add_liquidity_tx_hash)

        tx_hash_hex = add_liquidity_tx_hash.hex()

        # Retrieve pair address
        wbnb_addy = web3.to_checksum_address('0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd')
        factory_address = router.functions.factory().call()
        factory_address = web3.to_checksum_address(factory_address)
        factory = web3.eth.contract(address=factory_address, abi=await getContractAbi(factory_address))
        pair_address = factory.functions.getPair(token_address, wbnb_addy).call()

        if pair_address == '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000':
            return 'failed', 'failed'

        # If burn is set to True, burn liquidity
        if burn:
            burn_hash = await burn_liquidity(amount_token_desired, pair_address)
            return burn_hash, pair_address
        else:
            return tx_hash_hex, pair_address

    except Exception as er:
        print(f'Add liquidity transaction failed: {er}')
        return 'failed', 'failed'

